# eq operator in Perl for both characters and integers

Tags: perl

I was working on  simple password checker program using Perl , I was comparing two strings 
"abc@123" and " "abc" using eq operator Perl is treating both the strings as equal. Is there any way to compare a string having both characters and numbers with another string?

Comment: `'abc@123' eq 'abc'` is **not** true.

Comment: @ikegami I realized that, which is why I changed from double to single quotes to make the statement correct.

Answer (score 7):

Enable warnings!

```
use warnings;
my $x = "abc@123";
print $x;
```

`$x` *is* "abc" and you get a warning:

```
Possible unintended interpolation of @123 in string
```

telling you that you have interpolated the empty array @123 into your string.

With proper quoting:

```
my $x = 'abc@123';
if ( $x eq 'abc' ) {
    print "eq";
}
else {
    print "not eq";
}
```

you get 'not eq' as you would expect.

As TLP says, not using strict and warnings is asking for trouble.

Comment: You should add that not using `use strict; use warnings;` is asking for trouble.

Comment: That should really be a standard thing when posting a 'perl' question.